# Pig Latin exercise works, but only for one user inputed word. Not all words

Tags: ruby, arrays, each

I'm new to programming and I'm working with Ruby as my starter language. The below code works, but if someone inputs more than one word, the pigatize method only works on the first word and adds the additional ay or way to the last word. How do i get it to apply to each word a user inputs?

```
# If the first letter is a vowel, add "way" to the end
# If the first letter is a consonant, move it to the end and add "ay"

class PigLatin
  VOWELS =  %w(a e i o u)

  def self.pigatize(text)
    if PigLatin.vowel(text[0])
      pigalatin = text + 'way'
    else
      piglatin = text[1..-1] + text[0] + 'ay'
    end
  end

  def self.vowel(first_letter)
    VOWELS.include?(first_letter)
  end
end

puts 'Please enter a word and I will translate it into Pig Latin. Ippyyay!.'
text = gets.chomp
puts "Pigatized: #{PigLatin.pigatize(text)}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chiefly, you need to split the input string into words [with `String#split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split), using an expression like:

```
text.split(' ')
```

That produces an array of words, which you can loop over with an `.each` block and run the algorithm on each word, then reassemble them with `+=` and a space at the end `+ ' '`

Incorporating these things into your existing code looks like the following (with comments):

```
class PigLatin
  VOWELS =  %w(a e i o u)

  def self.pigatize(text)
    # Declare the output string
    piglatin = ''
    # Split the input text into words
    # and loop with .each, and 'word' as the iterator
    # variable
    text.split(' ').each do |word|
      if PigLatin.vowel(word[0])
        # This was misspelled...
        # Add onto the output string with +=
        # and finish with an extra space
        piglatin += word + 'way' + ' ' 
      else
        # Same changes down here...
        piglatin += word[1..-1] + word[0] + 'ay' + ' ' 
      end 
    end 
    # Adds a .chomp here to get rid of a trailing space
    piglatin.chomp
  end 

  def self.vowel(first_letter)
    VOWELS.include?(first_letter)
  end 
end
puts 'Please enter a word and I will translate it into Pig Latin. Ippyyay!.'
text = gets.chomp
puts "Pigatized: #{PigLatin.pigatize(text)}"
```

There are other ways to handle this than adding to the string with `+=`. You could, for example add words onto an array with an expression like:

```
# piglatin declared as an array []
# .push() adds words to the array
piglatin.push(word + 'way')
```

Then when it's time to output it, use `Array#join` to connect them back with spaces:

```
# Reassemble the array of pigatized words into a 
# string, joining the array elements by spaces
piglatin.join(' ')
```

There are alternatives to `.each..do` for the loop. You could use a for loop like

```
for word in text.split(' ')
  # stuff...
end
```

...but using the `.each do` is a bit more idiomatic and more representative of what you'll usually find in Ruby code, though the `for` loop is more like you'd find in most other languages besides Ruby.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. This works and I understand it now because of the way you explained it.